# Xamarin, WPF, UWP solution architecture MVVM (project referencing)

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, mvvm, uwp

I have been working on Xamarin Forms application (this question suits WPF and UWP as well) and came across a problem that I think can be have the roots in my current project architecture.

Here is an example of application similar to my current one:

Solution MyProject

```
 MyProject.GeoTracker
   GeoLocationProvider.cs
 MyProject
   MainViewModel.cs
   SettingsViewModel.cs
 MyProject.Android
 MyProject.iOS
 MyProject.Shared
```

`MyProject.GeoTracker` is referenced in `MyProject`, so that `MyProject` has reference of `MyProject.GeoTracker`.

In `SettingsViewModel.cs` I have an EventHandler:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SettingsChanged;
protected virtual void OnSettingsChanged() => this.SettingsChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
```

Then in MainViewModel.cs:

```
public MainViewModel(
  ISettingsViewModel settingsViewModel)
{
  this.SettingsViewModel = settingsViewModel;
  this.SettingsViewModel.SettingsChanged += this.OnSettingsChanged;

  this.GeoLocationProvider = new GeoLocationProvider();
  this.GeoLocationProvider.StartGeoTracking();
  this.GeoLocationProvider.GeoLocationChanged += this.OnGeoLocationChanged;
}
```

This way I am able to track Settings changes in my `MainViewModel.cs`.

Question: what if I want to do the same in `GeoLocationProvider.cs`? It is not possible to have circle reference in solution, so I am not able to reference `MyProject` in `MyProject.GeoTracker`. What is possible solution?

Comment: Move the relevant code into another library.

Comment: I'll give a reason for my upvote, too. It's that I've encountered the very reasonable scenario of Unit Testing my app where the app also has some Built-In Self Testing that uses elements of the Unit Test library to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

**td;dr** A circular reference can be avoided with an appropriate `interface`, an `event handler`, or any `Dependency Injection` scheme.

---

**INTERFACE**

The principle is that the place that "needs the work done" does NOT need to know what `class` performs the work. It just needs a way to say what it wants done.

I'll show an interface, rather than pick some DI library. A DI library makes details cleaner than what I do here.

1. Define an `interface` in `MyProject.GeoTracker`:

```cs
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void DoSomething(object obj);
}
```

2. Declare a `static` variable to hold an implementation of that interface:

```cs
public class MyClass1
{
    public ISomeInterface SomeInterface;
}
```

3. In `MyProject`, define the implementor of that interface:

```cs
class SomeInterfaceImpl ISomeInterface
{
    public void DoSomething(object obj)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

4. In `MyProject`, tell `MyProject.GeoTracker` what implementation to use:

```cs
MyProject.GeoTracker.MyClass1.SomeInterface = new SomeInterfaceImpl();
```

5. When `MyProject.GeoTracker` needs the work done, it does:

```cs
MyClass1.SomeInterface?.Invoke(...);
```

Which does nothing, if that variable has not been set.

---

**EVENTS**

An `event` is often an alternative to the above. Step #2 defines an event; Step #4 does `eventHandler += ...` to attach an action to perform on that event. This is a fundamental c# concept, that hopefully you have used many times, to get a standard library to execute your code, even though that library doesn't have a reference to your code. Think about that.

---

**DEPENDENCY INJECTION**

Everything else you need is elaborations on the above. Its often worth using a `Dependency Injection` library to manage the details cleanly.

---

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

- Often, you'll need to define additional `interface`s, in order to pass data back and forth. If you want `MyProject.GeoTracker` to act on a `MyProject.MyClass2` instance, define `interface MyProject.GeoTracker.IMyClass2` which exposes the needed members. Then `public class MyClass2 : IMyClass2`.
- Worst case, you'll need another DLL to hold shared `interface`s. So all your projects can refer to them. Personally, I've never encountered a situation that required that.
- Does this require more coding than if you could directly make a circular refernce?

Yes, but IMHO its worth it: it **documents** places where you are forcing a "reverse-dependency": making 'lower-level' code "aware" of something in 'higher-level' code.

Answer (score 0):

When I have to summon the dark forces of circular references this is my personal technique. "Your mileage many vary." Here I have a solution with class libraries `ClassLibraryA` and `ClassLibraryB`. Before I am through here, they'll successfully and safely reference each other.

```
namespace ClassLibraryA
{
    public class ClassA
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace ClassLibraryB
{
    public class ClassB
    {
    }
}
```

[image: Solution overview]

To bootstrap this scheme, the first Solution build is performed *before* they attempt to reference each other. As a matter of preference, I use a common path for both. The solution builds just fine. It has no reason to complain so far, right?.

[image: Common path]

But nothing stops me from invoking the **Browse...** from here:

[image]

...and so now I add the ClassLibraryA.dll to the ClassLibraryB References and vice versa in order to do this:

```
using ClassLibraryB;

namespace ClassLibraryA
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public ClassA()
        {
        }
        public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this:

```
using ClassLibraryA;

namespace ClassLibraryB
{
    public class ClassB
    {
        public ClassB()
        {
        }
        public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and finally this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var classA = new ClassA();
    classA.ClassB = new ClassB();

    var classB = new ClassB();
    classB.ClassA = new ClassA();

    Console.WriteLine($"{classA.GetType().Name} has {classA.ClassB.GetType().Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{classB.GetType().Name} has {classB.ClassA.GetType().Name}");
}
```

So this is one way to thread the needle that I've used in one flavor or another. I'm not claiming this is some kind of **The Answer** it's just something that's worked for me.

[image]

Comment: They couldn't do something crazy like instantiate each other in their respective CTors of course :)